# my perceptron could classify OR/AND but it could not classify NOR/NAND

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, perceptron

Here is my code in python

```
def error(y_desired, y):
    return y_desired != y


def step_func(weighted_sum, theta):
    return 1 if ((weighted_sum - theta) >= 0) else 0


def weight_adjustment(error, alpha, x_element):
    return error*alpha*x_element


def weighted_sum(w, x_epoch):
    weighted_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(w)):
        weighted_sum += w[i]*(x_epoch[i])
    return weighted_sum


def perceptron(x, y_desired, w, theta, alpha):
    cond = True
    epochs = 0
    while(cond == True):
        count = 0
        epochs += 1
        print(f'Epoch number - {epochs}')
        for epoch in range(len(x)):
            weighted_sums = round(weighted_sum(w, x[epoch]), 10)
            y = step_func(weighted_sums, theta)
            if error(y_desired[epoch], y):
                count += 1
                for weights in range(len(w)):
                    w[weights] = round(w[weights] + weight_adjustment(error = (y_desired[epoch] - y),
                                                   alpha = alpha,
                                                   x_element = x[epoch][weights]), 10)
            print(w)
        print('\n')
        if count == 0:
            cond = False
    print('Final Weights -')
    return w


x = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
y_desired = [0, 0, 0, 1]
w = [0.3, -0.1]
perceptron(x, y_desired, w, theta = 0.2, alpha = 0.1)
```

OR/AND works fine
but when I go for [1, 0, 0, 0]
it goes in an infinite loop. There is no difference in classification of AND/NAND/OR/NOR.
All can be linearly classified.

Did I miss something fundamentally or in weight training? Where I did the mistake?
If possible share the study material too.

Comment: Could you describe the code, show some imports, and explain what/where you think the error may be?

Comment: And please add a tag(s) for the library(s) you are using here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are rounding the weights, which is a bad habit to form. 
Secondly you demand 0 error while classification in general will be probability based.

I recommend https://stackabuse.com/creating-a-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python/
series of 3 articles that does a decent job explaining the basics.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely check the article and try to get an understanding of the line 'you demand 0 error while classification, in general, will be probability-based'   and for rounding off python is saying 0.3 - 0.1 = 0.1999999999998 that is why I used it

Comment: I see, what i meant by that (and you will find it in article #1 of the series as well), is that a classification perceptron outputs are more often than not indecisive. e.g: perceptron outputs 0.98, we use a threshold function and get 1 so we say the output is 1, when really the output was "Im pretty sure this is 1 based on training data, but not 100% sure".

Anyways, i wish you luck on your journey!